# How to Detect URL in text and convert it to link with python?

Tags: python, html

I have a page that contains a text `<p></p>`, how do I make the links placed in that text convert to href and can be clicked by the user.

Comment: Can you provide an example please

Comment: I am creating a blog, and my posts display text that may contain a link that displays as text, as follows: 

"Lorem Ipsum is simply the text https://google.com fictitious text of the printing and typesetting industry."

How can I make the text **https://google.com**, display as a href link?

Or in other words convert to this: `<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>`

Comment: Maybe you could try http://alexcorvi.github.io/anchorme.js/

Comment: Yes, indeed that is what I am looking for, thank you very much for the two answers, both are very helpful for me, I appreciate it.

Comment: No worries Jhonatan :)